# Source code of DXF export functionality in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to make some adjustments to the DXF Export functionality in QGIS 2.18.25. How can I get the source code of this functionality? Is it in Python?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code is available at github: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS

This is C++ application developed using Qt.

The functionality of exporting to DXF activated here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L5130-L5171

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! is it possible to add a plugin in cpp or a new functionality to QGIS like DXF Export in cpp ?

Comment: You can expand QGIS functionality via plugins on Python (preferable) or CPP. Search available plugins at http://plugins.qgis.org/. **Note**: Latest QGIS 3.4 LTR is not support plugins for 2.18.x. Plugin cookbook is here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/. In your case I advise you to start from plugin (new or modify existing). The QGIS sources modification is next step if plugin developing not suits you.

Comment: actually I already made some plugins in python but for example the DXF export functionality couldn't be as perfect as QGIS's. That's why instead of creating a plugin I intend to modify the existing one

Comment: This answer isn't quite correct -- the actual "guts" of the DXF export is located within https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/dxf/qgsdxfexport.cpp

Comment: @ndawson Do you carefully read the answer? I wrote "activated" - this mean the entry point of menu highlighted on screenshot.

Comment: is it possible to use 'Export DXF' functionnality from python console ?

Comment: Yes, you can find exported to python functions here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/python/core/dxf/qgsdxfexport.sip. The full set of exported functions is here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/release-2_18/python/core.

Comment: @dmitry-baryshnikov I did, but if the question is asking about the source code of the DXF export then the qgsdxfexport.cpp link is more direct.